# Effect of applying Hermitian conjugate of inversion operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, unitarity

I'm glad Victor Galitski's [monolith](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199232725) is finally out in English version, but I was confused by the following problem:

$$
\text{Find the Hermitian conjugate of the inversion operator }\hat{\Pi}: \hat{\Pi} \psi(x) \equiv \psi(-x).
$$

Based on my experience with QM, it's easy to see that
$$
\hat{\Pi} \hat{\Pi}\psi(x) \equiv \psi(x),\tag{1}
$$
as double inversions change nothing. Because of $\hat{\Pi}$ being unitary, $\hat{\Pi}\hat{\Pi}=I$ indicates $\hat{\Pi}=\hat{\Pi}^{-1}=\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}$. With this, we have
$$
\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi(x)=\psi(-x).\tag{2}
$$
Eqn.(2) agrees with the solution given in the book, but the book suggested another method that results in a slightly different effect of applying $\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}$ to $\psi(x)$. The method places $\hat{\Pi}$ in the following integral and then changes the variable to demonstrate what $\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi$ is, i.e.,
$$
\begin{align}
\int\psi^*(x)\hat{\Pi}\psi(x)dx&=\langle\psi|\hat{\Pi}\psi\rangle=\langle\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi|\psi\rangle\\
&=\int\psi^*(x)\psi(-x)dx\underbrace{=}_{y=-x}-\int\psi^*(-y)\psi(y)dy\\
\end{align}
$$
from this, we can conclude that
$$
-\psi^*(-x)=\left(\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi\right)^*\Rightarrow \hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi=-\psi(-x).\tag{3}
$$
Eqn. (3) contradicts (2), even though the only difference is a global factor $-1$. While a similar global factor was used in the definition of $\hat{\Pi}$ in other resources(e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(physics)#Possible_eigenvalues)), I'm still not very comfortable with what I got here. Should I stick to the first method and be cautious about Galitski's method?

**Revise the second method based on Valter's answer:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\hat{\Pi}\psi(x)dx&=\langle\psi|\hat{\Pi}\psi\rangle=\langle\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi|\psi\rangle\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\psi(-x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(-x)\psi(x)dx\\
\end{align}
$$
where the last equivalence holds because $-\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$.

Also, comparing $\psi^*(-x)\psi(x)$ with $\langle\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi|\psi\rangle$, we have
$$
\psi^*(-x)= (\hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi(x))^*\Rightarrow \hat{\Pi}^{\dagger}\psi(x)=\psi(-x)
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right and the other procedure is incorrect due to a *trivial calulus mistake*:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx =$$ (wrong!)$$-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(-x) dx\:.$$

Comment: Thank you! I should spot that in the first place... The OP is changed based on ur answer.